# How to append conditional styles in Next.js?

Tags: css, next.js

This is my trial:

```js
function Stroke2TextAndImage(props: Stroke2TextAndImageProps) {
  return (
    <div
      className={
        styles.container0 + " " + props.isLightGreenBackground == true
          ? styles.isLightGreenBackground
          : " "
      }
    >
```

Without condition I would apply `styles.container0`, but `styles.isLightGreenBackground` only if `props.isLightGreenBackground` is true.

Syntacs is ok, but style is not applied. do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the conditional part in parenthesis:

```js
function Stroke2TextAndImage(props: Stroke2TextAndImageProps) {
  return (
    <div
      className={
        styles.container0 +
        " " +
        (props.isLightGreenBackground === true
          ? styles.isLightGreenBackground
          : " ")
      }
    >
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Your current code will be evaluated like:

```js
if(Boolean(styles.container0 + " " + props.isLightGreenBackground) === true) 
    styles.isLightGreenBackground
else
    " "
```

Just a demo:

```js
console.log('foo' + ' ' + 'bar' == true ? 'hey' : 'there') // 'there'

console.log('foo' + ' ' + ('bar' == true ? 'hey' : 'there')) // 'foo there'
```

For more details refer: [Operator Precendence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

<sub>Recommendation: Use some utility like [`clsx`](https://github.com/lukeed/clsx) or [`classnames`](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) if you have many of such cases to avoid future issues.</sub>